# How to list directories and files in a Bash by script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to list directory tree, but I have to write script for it and as parameter script should take path to base directory. Listing should start from this base directory.

The output should look like this:

```
Directory: ./a
File: ./a/A
Directory: ./a/aa
File: ./a/aa/AA
Directory: ./a/ab
File: ./a/ab/AB
```

So I need to print path from the base directory for every directory and file in this base directory.

**UPDATED**

Running the script I should type in the terminal this: ".\test.sh /home/usr/Desktop/myDirectory" or ".\test.sh myDirectory" - since I run the test.sh from the Desktop level.
And right now the script should be run from the level of /home/usr/Dekstop/myDirectory"

I have the following command in my test.sh file:

```
find . | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g"
```

But It is the **command**, not shell code and prints the output like this:

```
DIR: dir1
    DIR: dir2
      fileA
    DIR: dir3
    fileC
fileB
```

How to print the path from base directory for every dir or file from the base dir? Could someone help me to work it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear what you want maybe,

```
find . -type d -printf 'Directory: %p\n' -o -type f -printf 'File: %p\n'
```

However to see the subtree of a directory, I find more useful

```
find "$dirname" -type f
```

To answer comment it can also be done in pure bash (builtin without external commands), using a recursive function.

```
rec_find() {
    local f
    for f in "$1"/*; do
        [[ -d $f ]] && echo "Directory: $f" && rec_find "$f"
        [[ -f $f ]] && echo "File: $f"
    done
}

rec_find "$1"
```

Comment: The output of the command find $1 -type d -printf 'Directory: %p\n' -o -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' is correct, but are you able to write script (shell code) to work as this command above?

Comment: Yes, but why to write more commands when one shorter can do the same. note that quote are missing around $1 : `find "$1" `.. in case of directory containing space or some meta characters

Comment: Thank you for help. Its kind of excercise to write scripts in bash

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tree` command. Key `-L` means max depth. Examples:

```
tree
.
├── 1
│   └── test
├── 2
│   └── test
└── 3
    └── test

3 directories, 3 files
```

Or

```
tree -L 1
.
├── 1
├── 2
└── 3

3 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: While the `tree` command is very useful, I don't see how this matches the desired output the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Create your `test.sh` with the below codes. Here you are reading command line parameter in system variable $1 and provides parameter to find command.

```
#!/bin/bash #in which shell you want to execute this script

find $1 | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g"
```

Now how will it work:-

```
./test.sh /home/usr/Dekstop/myDirectory #you execute this command
```

Here command line parameter will be assign into $1. More than one parameter you can use $1 till $9 and after that you have to use shift command. (You will get more detail information online).

So your command will be now:-

```
#!/bin/bash #in which shell you want to execute this script

find /home/usr/Dekstop/myDirectory | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g"
```

Hope this will help you.